# erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto." ao mostrar um valor null na view

Tags: c#, view, null

Dentro do C# MVC5, estou criando um formulario de cadastro de usuários com diversos campos. Um deles é o campo de Função (Gratificada), que o usuário pode ou não ter.

Segue a classe Usuário:

```
public class Usuarios
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(60)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Matrícula"),StringLength(7)]
    public string Matricula {get;set;}

    [DisplayName("DV"),Required]
    public int MatriculaDV {get;set;}

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string OAB {get;set;}

    [DisplayName("Gênero")]
    public Genero Genero { get; set; } 
    public bool Ativo {get;set;}

    [DisplayName("Data de Nascimento"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}")]
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Unidade")]
    public virtual int? UnidadesID {get;set;}
    public virtual Unidades Unidade {get;set;}

    [DisplayName("Cargo")]
    public virtual int? CargosID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cargos Cargo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Função")]
    public virtual int? FuncoesID {get;set;} //eis a funcao
    public virtual Funcoes Funcao {get;set;}

}
```

E a classe Funcoes:

```
public class Funcoes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    [StringLength(70)]
    public string Funcao { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Usuarios> Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

O formulário de inclusão permite acrescentar um novo registro sem função.

Porém, ao tentar listá-los, a view que contém a tabela gera o erro abaixo na linha em que tenta mostar um registro de função nula (linha @usuario.Funcao.Funcao):

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_tneo00cv.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma
>   instância de um objeto.

Segue a view Index do UsuarioController:

```
@model IList<Aplicacoes.Entidades.Usuarios>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Usuários";
}
<h4>Lista de Usuários</h4>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="Usuario/Form">Novo Usuário</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="Unidades/Index">Unidades</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="Cargo/Index">Cargos</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="Funcao/Index">Funções</a>
@*@Html.ActionLink("Novo Usuário", "Form", "Usuario", new { @class="btn btn-primary"})
@Html.ActionLink("Unidades", "Index", "Unidades", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })*@
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Matricula</th>
            <th>DV</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Cargo</th>
            <th>Função</th>
            <th>Unidade</th>
            <th>OAB</th>
            <th>Data Nasc.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var usuario in @Model.OrderBy(usuario => usuario.Nome))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@usuario.Matricula.ToUpper()</td>
                <td>@usuario.MatriculaDV</td>
                <td>@usuario.Nome.ToUpper()</td>
                <td>@usuario.Cargo.Cargo</td>
                <td>@usuario.Funcao.Funcao</td> //o erro ocorre aqui
                <td>@usuario.Unidade.Sigla</td>
                <td>@usuario.OAB</td>
                <td>@usuario.DataNascimento.ToShortDateString()</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Tentei contornar dessa maneira na própria View, mas não funcionou:

```
if(@usuario.Funcao == null)
{
    <td>-</td>
}else{
    <td>@usuario.Funcao.Funcao</td> //o erro acontece aqui novamente
}
```

Segue o UsuarioController para averiguação:

```
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{
    // GET: Usuario
    private UsuarioDAO uDao;
    private CargosDAO cDao;
    private FuncoesDAO fDao;
    private UnidadesDAO udDao;

    public UsuarioController(UsuarioDAO uDao, CargosDAO cDao, FuncoesDAO fDao, UnidadesDAO udDao)
    {
        this.uDao = uDao;
        this.cDao = cDao;
        this.fDao = fDao;
        this.udDao = udDao;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<Usuarios> usuarios = uDao.Lista();
        return View(usuarios);
    }

    public ActionResult Form()
    {
        ViewBag.Cargos = cDao.Lista().OrderBy(Cargos =>Cargos.Cargo);
        ViewBag.Funcoes = fDao.Lista().OrderBy(Funcoes => Funcoes.Funcao);
        ViewBag.Unidades = udDao.Lista().OrderBy(Unidades => Unidades.Nome);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Adiciona(Usuarios usuario)
    {
        uDao.Adiciona(usuario);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Remove(int id)
    {
        Usuarios usuario = uDao.BuscaPorId(id);
        uDao.Remove(usuario);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult Detalhes(int id)
    {
        Usuarios usuario = uDao.BuscaPorId(id);
        return View(usuario);
    }

    public ActionResult Atualiza(Usuarios usuario)
    {
        uDao.Atualiza(usuario);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

}
```

Entendo que o erro pede que eu inicie a variável antes. Porém não consigo imaginar onde posso inicar essa variável, uma vez que se trata de uma "classe dentro de uma classe".

Comment: Gente, ainda estou precisando de ajuda pra superar esse problema. Obrigado :)

Comment: Já verificou se todos os usuários da lista possuem Funções? Na sua **view** tente algo assim: `<td>@usuario.Funcao?.Funcao</td>`

Comment: Cadê seu método lista ()

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou adicionar um construtor na classe de usuários?

```
  public Usuarios()
    {
        this.FuncoesID = 0;
        this.Funcoes = new Funcoes();
    }
```

Comment: Bom dia, fiz uma tentativa mas com esse construtor ele limpou todas as funções dos usuários que tem essa informação =(
Tentei ```        public Usuarios()
        {
            if (this.Funcao == null)
            {
                this.FuncoesID = 0;
                this.Funcao = new Funcoes();
            }
        }```
mas não funcionou tb

Comment: Você pode tentar construir um construtor para a classe função iniciando os campos que estão dando erro.

Comment: Tentei `        public Funcoes()
        {
            if (this.Funcao== null)
            {
                this.Id = 0;
                this.Funcao = "-";
                this.Codigo = 0;
            }
        }` na classe função, mas não deu certo tb. Retornou o mesmo erro =/ (o erro mencionado na pergunta, não chegou a listar os usuários sem os nomes das funções)

Comment: @romalito se você remover o pedaço de código da view, ele funciona? Só pra ter certeza que é isto...

Comment: Funciona sim. Na realidade, se eu excluir o registro na tabela com o campo Função que for nulo, a lista processa normalmente.

Comment: Eu tive problema desse com SQL e C#, então passei a enviar um valor "0" (zero) ou " " (espaço) onde seria null pra não dar erro no retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar o ? para imprimir os possíveis objetos nulos.

```
   <tbody>
    @foreach (var usuario in @Model.OrderBy(usuario => usuario.Nome))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@usuario.Matricula?.ToUpper()</td>
            <td>@usuario.MatriculaDV</td>
            <td>@usuario.Nome.ToUpper()</td>
            <td>@usuario.Cargo?.Cargo</td>
            <td>@usuario.Funcao?.Funcao</td> //o erro ocorre aqui
            <td>@usuario.Unidade?.Sigla</td>
            <td>@usuario.OAB</td>
            <td>@usuario.DataNascimento?.ToShortDateString()</td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```